# Connecting Google Apps Script to personal computer to run a program

Tags: python, google-apps-script

I’m not sure if there is a better way of describing my issue, but here goes:

I have written a program on my personal computer (python) that I can run, but I want to run it when triggered by receiving an email automatically.

In other words, when I receive an email with a certain header/text, run this specific program.

What is a secure way of sending this signal to my computer such that it will queue to run when I am logged in? My computer is a laptop and is frequently asleep and I don’t want to lose the signal to run the program.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push, however this entails running a server which may be over-complicated from what I understand as your use case. 

A better approach may be to use the polling GMail API on user log-in

Comment: You could use a webapp that you poll with your computer and it scans your inbox for a particular email and if it finds in returns a value that you can use to trigger you program.  The webapp will be ready any time you're online and polling it.  Yes, you'll have write another program to poll the webapp.

Comment: To start running the code from an email you will have to run your own mail server. That is a complex approach, but you could use a workaround. You can modify your code to check your inbox in a time based manner, and to execute the required function when it finds the specified email. To help you to include this functionality, could you please share your code? That way we can get a look on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few months, I've come up with an answer - configuring your email with IMAP. I was able to do this with gmail.

There is a built-in IMAP library for python called [`imaplib`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imaplib.html) that allows you to do the trick.

Basically you can query the inbox and search for a file every X minutes, and run a command if a specific type of email is found.

(Idea from [`mrooney/minapi`](https://github.com/mrooney/mintapi/blob/master/mintapi/api.py#L62))